# How can I see what variables are available on the loaded page via the devel PHP Execute block?

Tags: 7, debugging

How can I see what variables are available to me on the page i am viewing via the PHP Execute block? I'm trying to do a dsm($node) but that doesnt seem to work. Neither does dsm($page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal doesn't define a global `$node` or `$page` object, those are created within the context of various functions during the page build.

To get the node object on a full node page, you can use [`menu_get_object()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7):

```
$node = menu_get_object();
```

For the page array, you'll need to implement [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  dpm($page);
}
```

As a general rule PHP's own [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) function will get you all the variables available in the current context. But it won't be useful to find those two particular vars as they won't be available in the context of a devel PHP form execution.

Comment: thanks.... what i dont understand is why is it called menu_get_object when your fetching the node object?

Comment: It is a bit confusing - it's returning the object (node, taxonomy term, user) that's attached to the current menu path. The function just defaults to use a node, if you were on a taxonomy term page you could use `menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2)` to get the `$term` object, etc.

Comment: confusing indeed...

Answer (score 3):

Drupal loads all variables into `$variables`.

So in the PHP block just load: `<?php dsm($variables); ?>`.

For dsm to work you need the Devel module installed.